# AppWarp onPrivateUpdateReceived doesn't work

Tags: appwarp

```
var codestring = this.ball + " " + this.ball.position["x"] + " " 
                 + this.ball.position["y"];  
_warpclient.sendPrivateUpdatePeers(enemy, codestring);
```

I use this function to send peers to the person with defined name enemy.

```
function onSendPrivateUpdateDone (result){
    console.log('Update done ' + result);
}
```

`onSendPrivateUpdateDone` works and write messages to person who send peers, here https://apphq.shephertz.com/appWarp/index#/testManager it's noted that my messages are sent, room is created and players are connected to the room, but the person who must accept message doesn't do that, because function `onPrivateUpdateReceived` callback does nothing.

```
onPrivateUpdateReceived(userName, msg){
    console.log("Username: "+userName);
    console.log("Message: "+msg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`onPrivateUpdateReceived` recieves msgs from the `tosendPrivateUpdate` method, you should change `sendPrivateUpdatePeers` to `sendPrivateUpdate` to work.